# How to sort a table on basis of date of Birth when using angular js

Tags: angularjs, sorting, date, html-table

I want to sort my table on the basis of date of Birth. I am using angular js in my code but it is not working  as it is sorting the date column as if date is a string. I am using below code for sorting-

```
 <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'dob'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          Date of birth 
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'dob' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            <span ng-show="sortType == 'dob' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          </a>
        </th>
```

I have created a plunker here-
https://plnkr.co/edit/6jX3lnqH6jVo6u00qvvk?p=preview

Can any one tell me how can I achieve that?

Comment: You will have to parse field to date then only you can apply sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the date of births as Date objects, and then use formatters to display the correct format in the view

```
"dob": new Date(1980, 0, 12)
```

See https://plnkr.co/edit/1Yupcexjb2DOJinTyTds?p=preview